# representing an entity which has variable length of categories and sub categories

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a Brands category which has to be displayed on selecting a particular category. And on top of that if i select a  sub category the brand list must be filtered according to the sub category. Another issue is that the hierarchy of the subcategories is variable depending on the product.

Brands table:

```
 Brand_id|brand_name
 101     | xyz
```

brand_cat table:

```
 brand_id| category_id
 101     | 001
 101     | 011
 101     | 111
```

category table"

```
 cat_id| parent_id
 001   | -
 011   | 001
 111   | 011
```

In the example: brand_cat table has a lot of redundancy. But I need the brands to be shown based on the category or/and sub categories I select.
If my table structure is right. How would I extract brands based on the category selected.

Comment: As far as I know, it can't be done purely in MySQL without client-side looping or a stored procedure. (Technically, if you know the maximum "depth", you can do it with a single query by joining to the category table "depth" times; but even then it will be a bit difficult to get the inner category "nodes".)

Comment: Depth is the problem.  But there is a limit for the depth though. Like around four levels . would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
SELECT brand_name
FROM brand_cat, brands
WHERE category_id='011' AND
      brands.Brand_id=brand_cat.brand_id
```

?

Edit: getting subcategories as well

```
SELECT brand_name
FROM brand_cat, brands, (SELECT cat_id
                         FROM category
                         WHERE parent_id='011') t
WHERE brand_cat.category_id='011' AND
      Brands.Brand_id=brand_cat.brand_id AND
      Brands.Brand_id=t.cat_id
```

Comment: this is the current code that I am using. But I am more worried about the data redundancy in brand_cat table. Was wondering if there is another way to store such data where you don't know the depth.

Comment: Does this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141815/2846982](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141815/2846982)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you all categories and their subcategories for a brand...as long as the depth is no more than 4:

```
SELECT t1.node_id
FROM treenode_table AS n0
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t1 ON n0.node_id = t1.node_id OR n0.node_id = t1.parent_node_id
WHERE n0.parent_node_id = @originalNode
UNION
SELECT t2.node_id
FROM treenode_table AS n0
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t1 ON n0.node_id = t1.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t2 ON t1.node_id = t2.parent_node_id
WHERE n0.parent_node_id = @originalNode
UNION
SELECT t3.node_id
FROM treenode_table AS n0
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t1 ON n0.node_id = t1.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t2 ON t1.node_id = t2.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t3 ON t2.node_id = t3.parent_node_id
WHERE n0.parent_node_id = @originalNode
UNION
SELECT t4.node_id
FROM treenode_table AS n0
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t1 ON n0.node_id = t1.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t2 ON t1.node_id = t2.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t3 ON t2.node_id = t3.parent_node_id
INNER JOIN treenode_table AS t4 ON t3.node_id = t4.parent_node_id
WHERE n0.parent_node_id = @originalNode
;
```

Ok, after a bunch of edits, that should work. (I've generalized it because I tested it against similar data I have.)